# Обработка AJAX - запроса

Tags: javascript, jquery

Получаю страницу ajax - запросом

```
$.ajax({
url: 'sortmonth',
success: function(data){        
}
});
```

Как получить данные из конкретного div?К примеру в data передалось:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="ru-RU">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<div id = 'container'>
</div>
</body>
```

Как получить данные из div 'container'?

Comment: прямо из data не меняя страницу html?

Comment: document.getElementById('container').innerHtml

Comment: @Vitalii этого элемента не будет на странице, html-код же получен через AJAX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну так давайте [сделаем...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser)

```js
var dynamicPage = `<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="ru-RU">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
DATA 
</div>
</body>`;
var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString(dynamicPage,"text/html");
var val = doc.getElementById('container').innerHTML;
console.log(val);
```

Плюсы: Не используем сторонних библитоек. Получаем объект с которым можно работать как с обычным документом. 
Минусы: Формально это технология эксперементальная. Но поддерживается всеми браузерами с ИЕ 10. ИЕ9 не поддерживает.

Answer (score 2):

На jQuery так:

```
var myDivData = $(data).find('div#container').html();
```

Comment: Этого элемента не будет на странице, html-код же получен через AJAX

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать метод [`.load()`](https://jquery-docs.ru/load/)

> Метод `.load()` позволяет указать часть удаленного документа для вставки. Это доступно при помощи специального синтаксиса в параметре url. Если один или несколько символов пробела включены в строку, то первое слово, после первого пробела, будет предполагать jQuery селектор, который определит какая часть будет вставлена.

Если вам нужно вставить полученный HTML-код на страницу:

```
$('селектор, куда нужно вставить').load('sortmonth #container')
```

Если вам нужно получить именно сам HTML-код:

```
var $temp = $('<div>').load('sortmonth #container', function () { 
  console.log($temp.html()) // $temp.html() HTML-код контейнера #container
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Делайте следующим образом:

```
var html = $('<div />').append(data);
var container = data.find('#container');

console.log(container);
```